# Can't find location of files after running drush make

Tags: drush

I am creating a drush .make file for a site.  I have generated the drush.make file using `drush make-generate` and then updated the file as necessary.  I am now trying to use the .make file to create a new site.

To do this I first change to the directory where I wish to install the new site.  I then run the command `drush make qmlc.make`.  Drush asks me if I want to "Make new site in the current directory? (y/n)".  I reply "y" and then drush begins building the site.

The problem is that after the build has finished, the current directory is empty, except for the qmlc.make file.

Why are the files not appearing in the directory? If they are not here, then where are they?

Answer (score 1):

Look for errors and warnings in the output of the make command. An empty directory is often the result of an error. This leaves your install directory in the drush temp location (usually `/tmp/drush-xxxx`).

You can add the `--force-complete` argument ignore errors and to copy the directory in to place anyway. But it's probably worth figuring out what the errors are.

`drush make --force-complete qmlc.make`

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/commands/make/make.drush.inc#L58